# "Move comments to chat" triggers auto and manual flagging and suspension

Tags: bug, comments, chat, flags, chat-ban

A recent moderation of moving a comment discussion to chat resulted in a user's comment to be flagged multiple times and the user was hit with a chat auto suspension.

No judgement on that users specific comment, but it seems unfair that a comment that would be considered okay on a site to be subjected to the flagging behavior in chat through no fault of the commenter. This seems like unintended behavior and almost a bug if autoflagging is involved.

**Should comments moved to chat have a special status to prevent this domino effect?**

Comment: The comment in question was also flagged on the main site as well. I'll confess it was my fault for taking too long to delete the comment from the main site that led to this situation.

Comment: Broadly speaking, any unexpected behavior could be categorized as bug, [or feature](//www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/1w1u3o/bug_vs_feature/) if you'd like `:)`

Answer (score 4):

It's very hard to imagine any kind of comment that would be okay *only* on a particular site, but would get r/a deleted in chat. Ideally, any such comments are cleaned up before moving to chat, because chat moderation isn't limited to just one particular site.

In this case, it was a user that moved the discussion, so no moderator came by to clean up first. But the comment wasn't appropriate on the main site either, as confirmed in [the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/361631/move-comments-to-chat-triggers-auto-and-manual-flagging-and-suspension/361633#comment1206563_361633).

Moderators sometimes miss things like this, especially on very long comment threads or if a user moves stuff to chat before a moderator has had time to clean things up. It is then very useful that chat comments can still be flagged. So giving those a special status to avoid further moderation is a bad idea.

While flagging behaviour in chat in general can, rarely, lead to 'unfair' situations like you describe, in such cases you can find a friendly site moderator on that user's behalf to correct the issue: Those site mods can see deleted chat messages, can agree the content wasn't out of line for the site and that the chat suspension is overdone, and if you get them within 30 minutes they can override any chat suspension that's left. I had someone do that for me once, when one of my chat messages got flagged in a r/a flag storm.

Comment: *It's very hard to imagine any kind of comment that would be okay only on a particular site, but would get r/a deleted in chat.* Keep in mind that as soon as a single user flags a message, *all* 10k+ users on the same chat server are notified of it, of whom many may be on sites that don't accept such comments, and as they're only shown the message contents and not much other context (such as the parent site of the room, or the fact that it was moved from comments) they might jump in and handle the flag as valid. It's not nearly as uncommon as a result.

Comment: The sensibilities on chat run hotter than on the normal sites, and site comment flags aren't handed off to other normal users. What could have been a deletion without comment by a mod turns into a auto suspension on chat. And by the time a mods attention is turned to a user appealing a chat flag or flags the harm is already done.

Comment: The special status wouldnt be preventing the comment from being flagged, but make it so those flags only go to diamond mods. Maybe preferably only the ones on the parent site. Like if they were still non-chat comments.

Comment: @sonic and not to mention briganding on chat is simple because of it. Some cliques in a chat can easily have someone suspended through flagging and then approving each other's flags.

Comment: As Tinkeringbell says, in this instance, the comment was not appropriate on the main site either. What I should have done was delete it before moving the comments to chat. I'll be more alert to this type of issue in the future.

Comment: @DMGregory I just realized you could've done nothing to prevent that: It was a user that moved the comments to chat, so there was no moderator involved in the moving at all. I edited my post accordingly.

Comment: @Sonic That first flag still has to be cast though, and that's most likely to be done by someone that is familiar with the site, and knows that this won't have been okay on the site itself either. And given DMGregory's comment, it's now pretty clear that this wasn't a case of a message that was okay for the site but not the chat, so there was no clash between site users or 10k chat users having different standards.

Comment: As for the harm done @cde ... 30 minutes without chat can be survived, I do it every night while sleeping. It's a tad frustrating, but not more. It's a very limited harm, though if you have any evidence that users are ganging up to flag other users out of chat repeatedly (or if there is anyone that thinks this is happening to them), that might be worth a moderator flag on the site of the chatroom this usually happens on, or a mail to Contact Us. Moderators *can* look into that or ask CMs for help.

Comment: As for making those flags go only to moderators or site moderators... The whole point here is kinda moot: The comment wasn't okay on the site and it's not okay in chat either, so there's little to argue that either should happen for the reason you gave (comments that are okay on a site ending up deleted in chat). There are some other good reasons to have e.g. chat modator flags go to site moderators only (one is that they may have more context about their problem users than all networkwide mods).

Comment: I understand regarding that comment. It was only that it brought the situation up, not in defense of the specific comment. But c'est la vie.